# -Bash Shell Script "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, npm, nvm

Pretty new to coding and I am running into an error I've never seen before and would really appreciate any help navigating this :( Thank you!

I wanted to delete nvm, so I removed the folder following the advice given on StackOverflow. That FINALLY successfully deleted node from my mac (wanted to uninstall because I was running into dependency errors). The I used brew install to reinstall node. I can find the path to the node file (using  `which node`). However when I run `node -v` I get the following bash (shell script??) error: `-bash: /Users/Cindy/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node: No such file or directory`

I also followed [#1219](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1219?fbclid=IwAR1pSYu-JWKOgYMFCvbcrswfSCDSLdAysxTyHxA_afD9k_NMx5OOgZjiM1A) and went into my bash_profile to delete the lines related to nvm. Now I don't know how to move forward with this.

I just want to be able to download node and run it properly to prepare for an interview in React and JS but I ran into these nasty bugs instead and morale is low. I'm lost now and I'm not sure if I just completely ruined my computer.

Comment: Is that file a script or a binary executable? If the former, read the first line to find the interpreter. If the latter, use `ldd` to look at which shared libraries it's trying to use.

Comment: By the way -- personally, I'd use Nix rather than Homebrew; it replaces and obsoletes `npm` and `nvm` (as well as similar tools for other languages), and is designed in such a way that you can't accidentally delete a dependency of a Nix-installed package.

Comment: Hi, I actually called my professor and we ran the command `bash -r` and then exited it and then it ran fine. Thank you thought!